# Can superoperators work in Monte Carlo solver in QuTip?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, qutip, master-equation

The Monte Carlo solver works with kets instead of density matrices. And it doesn't allow a superoperator (which acts on density matrices or superkets) as a collapse operator. Since my master equation has lindblad dissipators (which are superoperators), I have trouble using mcsolve.
The only way I can think of is converting the initial state to a superket. But that has type operator-ket and mcsolve isn't allowing this. Also, that added dimension seems inefficient.
How can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: What does your system look like? Do your Lindblad dissipators have to be superoperators? What's preventing you from treating them as regular operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue in QuTip's github repo and got an answer:

> Superoperator in mcsolve will be supported in QuTip 5.0

Here's a link to that issue:
https://github.com/qutip/qutip/issues/2060#issuecomment-1385475587